# How to validate input using RxJava?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have the following code

```
submitButtonClickObservable
    .withLatestFrom(txtInputChangesObservable)
    .subscribe{  }
```

It works well, but i want to handle clicking the submit button while the text input is not used and show the validation error. Is it possible to do it only with Rx without using variables like `var text: CharSequence` or accessing EditText value?

withLatestFrom marble:
http://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom

Comment: Can you edit this to explain where `txtInputchangesObservable` comes from?

It looks like you can just do your validation right there in the `subscribe` block, no? Perhaps I'm missing context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to add `.mergeWith(Observable.just(""))` to `txtInputChangesObservable`.
And now `subscribe{ }` block works on button click even if user didn't use the text input

```
@Test
fun textObs(){
    val submitButtonClickObservable = Observable.just(Any(), Any())
    val txtInputChangesObservable = Observable.empty<CharSequence>()
            .mergeWith(Observable.just(""))
    val testObserver = submitButtonClickObservable
            .withLatestFrom(txtInputChangesObservable).test()
    testObserver.assertValueCount(2)
}
```